# External Dictionary Reference in VB

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I am creating a project for school, similar to the letters section in “Countdown”. Is there an easy way to reference an external dictionary or create a dictionary in Visual Basic to check that created words are actual words in the dictionary? When I search all that comes up is VB object dictionaries instead of an English dictionary.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the SO. Do you just need to compare your word against a list of words (for example read from a file), or against an online resource (which is probably very hard for a school project)? Good luck with your project.

Comment: Honestly whatever would be easiest. By your response a file with a list of words would be the easiest method? If need be I’m assuming I could copy all/majority of the dictionary into the file for more accuracy.

Comment: I can't answer your question (because I don't know VB), but it sounds like the easiest solution for your specific problem. There are [multiple](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) lists of english words in the wild, you can probably use any of them, just be sure to check the allowed usage, add zour source to your project-writeup and, if you really want to be a completionist, write an answer here how you solved it in the end, for anyone in the future who has the same problem.

Comment: If you have a source of words, on the VB side, I'd guess that you'd want to load it into a `HashSet` since you're just interested in existence, not in mapping it to something else.

Comment: See if NetSpell helps. It is available as Nuget Package. See your Nuget manager.